# Erro ao conectar o Postgres em remotamente

Tags: linux, postgresql, ubuntu

Estou tendo problemas ao conectar ao banco de dados da empresa, estou acessando de casa. Meus outros colegas conseguem acessar normalmente.

Tanto via `pgAdmin` quanto `terminal` venho enfrentando problema. Estranho que consigo acessar outros serviços como `SVN` ou `Redmine`.

```
diego@diego-ThinkPad-X230:~$ sudo su postgres
[sudo] password for diego: 
postgres@diego-ThinkPad-X230:/home/diego$ psql -h paradigmainternet.ddns.com.br -p 5432
psql: could not connect to server: Não há rota para o host
    Is the server running on host "<endereço>" (<ip>) and accepting
    TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
```

Onde eu coloquei `<endereço>` e `<ip>` se referem ao endereço ddns e ip onde eu os retirei por segurança.

Queria saber se tem algo a se fazer para conectar pq eu não consigo daqui de casa acessar o banco de dados do postgres

Answer (score 1):

Você precisa liberar a permissão no arquivo:

/var/lib/pgsql/data/pg_hba.conf

Adicione uma linha para liberar um endereço ou faixa de IPs:

```
host    all         all         192.168.94.0 255.255.255.0      md5
```

Na duvida de uma olhada na documentação:
http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/auth-pg-hba-conf.html

Comment: Ok, vou verificar